# Как настроить Spring Сontroller возвращать либо html, либо jsp

Tags: spring-mvc, spring, java, java-ee

Мне нужно, чтобы определённые контроллеры возвращали .html, другие же - .jsp.
Проблема в InternalResourceViewResolver - у него указан суффикс:

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver
            = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}
```

Как видно, он всегда приклеит окончание .jsp. Удалил суффикс,  добавил

`<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />`

в свой xml конфиг, как сказано [здесь, на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479213/how-to-serve-html-files-with-spring), но страница html не вызывается вообще. Как я ни пытался делать запрос - static/page.html и т.д.

**И ещё один вопрос:**

В некоторых гайдах в файле-конфиге DispatcherServlet (web.xml) имеется такой маппинг:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Но а в некоторых элемент `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` имеет значение *.htm вместо слэша.
Что означают эти значения и какая разница между ними?

Comment: Я написал вам ответ к первому вопросу, а при попытке отправить получил ошибку. Теперь уж подробно писать не буду, поэтому вот: создайте два view resolver-а и назначьте им различный приоритет. Второй вопрос лучше было задавать отдельным вопросом.

Comment: Мне нужно статический ресурс вернуть. Какие ещё приоритеты?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть, как минимум, два варианта:

1) через view resolver-ы. В этом случае вам нужно определить два разных view resolver-а, один будет искать JSP-файлы (как сейчас), а второй HTML-файлы. И задать им различные приоритеты. Тогда сначала будет вызываться один резолвер и если он не найдет соответствующего файла, то передаст управление другому, тот найдет и вернет что нужно. Но в этом случае для каждого HTML-файла также придется создать по методу в контроллере (либо написать несколько `<mvc:view-controller/>`)

2) раздавать html-файлы сами по себе, через `<mvc:resources/>` В этом случае укажите `<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/WEB-INF/static/" />` и положите ваши html-файлы в `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/static`

На второй вопрос, вижу, вам [уже ответили](http://javatalks.ru/posts/232317).

Comment: ошибка была в том, что я отправлял имя ресурса html без редиректа. Делаю как в п.2: и указываю контроллеру в конце return "redirect:/static/page.html". Работает. Спасибо.